# validating sys.argv[] arguments in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using sys.argv[] arguments in my python script.

```
val=sys.argv[1]

Print (val)
```

So here, my sys.argv[1] value will be text. I need to validate whether its text or something else. I googled and found that argparse may help me in doing this kind of test. But i was not able to understand it. Can someone help me.

Comment: What kind of pattern? Can you use a regular expression to test it?

Comment: here, my argument value will be text. I googled it argparse may help in validating the value. But am so new to it, so not able to understand.

Comment: That's not what `argparse` if for, it's for specifying command-line options and their associated arguments.

Comment: If you just want to check if a string matches a pattern, use a regular expression. The fact that it's in `argv` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar i added little more description to my question. Probably its little bit more clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by "text or something else"? What else could it be?

Comment: Using command line arguments without validating what it has, may cause some attack. So i want to avoid this possibilty here.

Comment: Everything you type on the command line is text, so you need to be more specific. What patterns do you want to allow, what are you trying to block?

Comment: I want to avoid irrelevant charcters like $@ etcc

Comment: am i clear Barmar?

Comment: That's a very good use for a regexp. `if re.search(r'[$@]', argv[1]): print("Invalid")`

Comment: Actually after writing a script we use one scanning tool called checkmarx, to check for vulnerabilities. So I have a code where i used sys.argv[1], at this particular point checkmarx is giving me this warning. I ahve mentioned the error link below. https://cx.dell.com/CxWebClient/ScanQueryDescription.aspx?queryID=3572&queryVersionCode=92129952&queryTitle=Header_Injection

Comment: Please refer this error, probably it may give you little bit understanding of my question.

Comment: That link isn't working for me, it just spins.

Comment: And i will try your solution in my script, and let you know whether its avoiding  this error :-).

Comment: oh !! No it should work actually :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression. For instance, if you only want to allow letters, numbers, and whitespace:

```
import re

if re.search(r'[^a-z\d\s]', sys.argv[1], re.I):
    print("Invalid argument")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: How can i allow underscore(_) and dot (.) in my argument  apart from alphabet??

Comment: Just add those characters inside the brackets. That's the list of all the characters allowed.

Comment: Also, you can use `\w` to match letters, numbers, and underscore.

Comment: @ Barmar , do you have a idea of using argparse package to validate sys.argv[] argument?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `argparse`, so I don't know how it would be used for this purpose.

Comment: As I said above, I think it's mainly for parsing options, I don't know if it can validate.

Comment: Okay Barmar..Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

Like most programming tasks, there are several ways to tackle this:

1. Manual parsing

```py
import sys
import os.path


def show_help():
   print("Help screen...")

flag_set=False  # default to off
outfile="out.txt"
infile="in.txt"

i = 1  # 0 is the filename of the script
while i < len(sys.argv):
   arg = sys.argv[i]
   i += 1

   if arg == "-h" or arg == "--help":
       show_help()
       sys.exit(0)
   elif arg == "-f" or arg == "--flag":
       flag_set=True
   elif arg == "-o" or arg == "--outfile":
       outfile=sys.argv[i]  # ignoring len check for brevity
       i += 1
   elif arg == "-i" or arg == "--infile":
       infile=sys.argv[i]  # ignoring len check for brevity
       # Simple parameter validation
       if not os.path.exists(infile):
           print("Input file '", infile, "' not found.")
           sys.exit(0)
       i += 1
   # ... for any other args you want

if flag_set:
    print("Flag was set")

print("Reading from:", infile)
print("Outputting to:", outfile)
```

You can do any kind of validation you want with simple logic such as this.

2. Handy-dandy libraries (like argparse)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

There is no "wrong" way to do it, use whatever gets the job done for you!  But do try to stick to standard flags, like -h for help, etc.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with validating that the argument is only ordinary text without any punctuation characters?

Comment: @ steve , I tried to understand validation using argparse package, but i failed miserably. Can you please help me with the syntax.